# CSS, create a line next to text

Tags: html, css, text, line

I've read multiple threads without success.

I'm looking for help creating a line next to text in CSS. I'm not allowed to change the HTML code so adding a span element to the html code is not a solution for me.

This is what it looks like.

```
<legend>Text</legend>
```

and i want to create a line like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1zfx.jpg

Any solution to it without changing the html-code?

Comment: legend {
 color: #0071BC;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000; 
 line-height: 0.1em;
 margin: 10px 0px 20px;
}

This is what i've come up with so far but it just creates a line though it and im not able to get it behind..

Comment: Very easy to do with pseudo classes - :before, :after. Since  I'm on my phone, I will let someone else demo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
legend { height: 18px; position: relative; background: #fff; display: inline-bock; margin-left: 5px; } 
legend:before { content: ""; display: block; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: -5px; right: -100px; height: 1px; border-top: 1px solid red; z-index: -1; }
```